# problema con checkbox y php

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

Tengo un check-box que el usuario indicara respectivos meses de un formulario, logro hacer que envíe si selecciona enero y febrero pero si selecciona otros meses mas o enero, marzo diciembre por decir algo no los guarda en la base de datos.

```
<?php

if (
  $_POST['01'] == '01'
){
  $consulta = "
  INSERT INTO gastonocomun
  VALUES(
    '','$monto','$tipo',
    '2018-01-01','','',
    '','','','','','','','','','$gasto')
    ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
  }

  else if (
    $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
    $_POST['02'] == '02'
  ){
    $consulta = "
    INSERT INTO gastonocomun
    VALUES(
      '','$monto','$tipo',
      '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','',
      '','','','','','','','','','$gasto')
      ";
      $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    } 

    else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03'
    ){
      $consulta = "
      INSERT INTO gastonocomun
      VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '','','','','','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
        $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
        $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
        $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
        $_POST['04'] == '04'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','','','','','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','','','','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '','','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07' and 
      $_POST['08'] == '08'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','2018-08-01','','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07' and 
      $_POST['08'] == '08' and 
      $_POST['09'] == '09'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01','','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07' and 
      $_POST['08'] == '08' and 
      $_POST['09'] == '09' and 
      $_POST['10'] == '10'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01',
        '2018-10-01','','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07' and 
      $_POST['08'] == '08' and 
      $_POST['09'] == '09' and 
      $_POST['10'] == '10' and 
      $_POST['11'] == '11'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01',
        '2018-10-01','2018-11-01','','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }

      else if (
      $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
      $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
      $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
      $_POST['04'] == '04' and 
      $_POST['05'] == '05' and 
      $_POST['06'] == '06' and 
      $_POST['07'] == '07' and 
      $_POST['08'] == '08' and 
      $_POST['09'] == '09' and 
      $_POST['10'] == '10' and 
      $_POST['11'] == '11' and 
      $_POST['12'] == '12'
      ){
        $consulta = "
        INSERT INTO gastonocomun 
        VALUES(
        '','$monto','$tipo',
        '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01',
        '2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01',
        '2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01',
        '2018-10-01','2018-11-01','2018-12-01','$gasto')
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
      }
      ?>
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="monto">Fechas a cargar:</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="01" value="01" > Enero<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="02" value="02"> Febrero<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="03" value="03"> Marzo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="04" value="04"> Abril<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="05" value="05"> Mayo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="06" value="06"> Junio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="07" value="07"> Julio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="08" value="08"> Agosto<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="09" value="09"> Septiembre<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="10" value="10"> Octubre<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="11" value="11"> Noviembre<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="12" value="12"> Diciembre<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que se podria optimizar el codigo pero lo que sucede es que es que tienes que negar las otras opciones es decir else if ($_POST['01'] == '01' and $_POST['02'] == '02' and $_POST['03'] == '03' and POST['04'] == ' ' and POST['05'] == ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio tu lógica en el `if` esta diciendo que la condición tiene que ser **Si ambos**, A y B (AND) es cierta entonces...

Hasta que no se cumpla esa condición, que por ejemplo en:

```
else if ($_POST['01'] == '01' and $_POST['02'] == '02' ){

 $consulta = "
 INSERT INTO gastonocomun  
 VALUES(
  '','$monto','$tipo',
  '2018-01-01','2018-02-01',
  '','','','','','','','','','','$gasto')";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

}
```

Es que únicamente **si y solo si** `Enero` y `Febrero` están marcados se debe cumplir. Pero si resulta que puedes saltarte un mes como por ejemplo:

```
else if (
 $_POST['01'] == '01' and 
 $_POST['02'] == '02' and 
 $_POST['03'] == '03' and 
 $_POST['04'] == '04' ){
```

Si aquí no marco `Marzo` pero si `Abril`, este código no se ejecutaría, ni ningún otro.

Así que por un lado, en la practica deberías de guardar en un array los checkbox marcados, y esto lo logras, diciéndole en `"Name"` que es un arreglo.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="01" > Enero<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="02"> Febrero<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="03"> Marzo<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="04"> Abril<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="05"> Mayo<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="06"> Junio<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="07"> Julio<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="08"> Agosto<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="09"> Septiembre<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="10"> Octubre<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="11"> Noviembre<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="12"> Diciembre<br>
```

Luego recorremos el arreglo con un **Foreach()** y obtenemos los valores, de cada Checkbox.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {

}
```

y dependiendo de su valor, haces la inserción en la BD según lo manejes. Puedes separar los meses en Variables separadas por meses, y le pasas las variables a la consulta, cuestión de que, si no existe, quede vacío.

EDIT> $Query

Tu Query deberia quedar algo así:

```
$consulta = "
INSERT INTO gastonocomun  
VALUES('','$monto','$tipo','$ene','$feb','$mar','$abr','$may','$jun','$jul',
'$ago','$sep','$oct','$nov','$dic','$gasto')
";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
```

La idea del **foreach** es recorrer los Checkbox para determinar los que están seleccionados y darle los valores a sus respectivas variables ($ene, $feb, etc).

El condicional if, deberías utilizarlo únicamente para validar que un Checkbox ha sido seleccionado, y así mandar el Query.

Comment: realice fue lo que coloque como respuesta arriba pero aun sin conseguir lo esperado /

Comment: un or no ayudaria mejor? aun quede en lo que publique como respuesta abajo :/

Comment: @AndersonRey respuesta actualizada, para darte una idea de como debería quedar el Query.

Comment: Recuerda, si la respuesta te fue de utilidad marcala. 

Y comenta tus resultados.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$mes= $_POST['mes[]'];


foreach ($array as $mes) {

$valor=$array;

switch ($valor[1]) {
case '01':
$ene;
break;
case '02':
$feb;
break;
case '03':
$mar;
break;
case '04':
$abr;
break;
case '05':
$may;
break;
case '06':
$jun;
break;
case '07':
$jul;
break;
case '08':
$ago;
break;
case '09':
$sep;
break;
case '10':
$oct;
break;
case '11':
$nov;
break;
case '12':
$dic;
break;
}


if ($_POST['01'] == '01' and $_POST['02'] == '02' and $_POST['03'] == '03' and $_POST['04'] == '04' and $_POST['05'] == '05' and $_POST['06'] == '06' and $_POST['07'] == '07' and $_POST['08'] == '08' and $_POST['09'] == '09' and $_POST['10'] == '10' and $_POST['11'] == '11' and $_POST['12'] == '12'  ){

$consulta = "INSERT INTO gastonocomun  VALUES('','$monto','$tipo','2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01','2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01','2018-10-01','2018-11-01','2018-12-01','$gasto')";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

}







}




?>
```